# Let $T,S$ be unilateral shifts in $H,K$ and $A\in B(H,K)$ a contraction. If $S^*A=AT^*$, then why is $A$ a transposed infinite Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, interpolation, toeplitz-matrices

Let $H, K$ be Hilbert spaces.

As the **Toeplitz Matrix**, I define an operator $P_n$ in the form:

$$P_n = \begin{pmatrix}
        Q_0 & 0 & 0  & \ldots & 0 \\
        Q_1 & Q_0 & 0  & \ldots & 0\\
        Q_2 & Q_1 & Q_0  & \ldots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
        Q_{n-1} & Q_{n-2} & Q_{n-3} & \ldots & Q_0
        \end{pmatrix}$$

where $Q_n \in B(H, K)$.

Here, an infinite Toeplitz matrix would be simply $P_{\infty}$.

As **unilateral shifts**, I define:

$$T = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
        I & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
        0 & I & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
        0 & 0 & I & 0 & \ldots\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & I & \ldots\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

$$S = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
        I & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
        0 & I & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
        0 & 0 & I & 0 & \ldots\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & I & \ldots\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

for $T \in B(H)$, $S \in B(K)$.

So if we now have an intertwining operator $A \in B(H, K)$ for $T^*$ and $S^*$ i.e. $$S^* A = A T^*$$ then why is the form of this operator (if a contraction) the one of the transposed infinite Toeplitz matrix (what I mean is: *Why is then $A$ a transposed infinite dimensional lower triangular matrix with operators as their elements*)?

For more literature about this if needed, you can find more in *"The Commutant Lifting Approach to Interpolation Problems"* by Foias and Frazho, more precisely in the chapter about the **Nevanlinna-Pick interpolation problem**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that $A,T,S$ are not operators from and to $H$ or $K$ but from and to $\bigoplus^\bot_{n\in\Bbb N}H$ or $\bigoplus^\bot_{n\in\Bbb N}K.$

$T_{i,j}=I$ if $i=j+1$ and $0$ else, hence $(T^*)_{i,j}=I$ if $j=i+1$ and $0$ else. Same for $S.$ Hence (using that $(UV)_{i,j}=\sum_kU_{i,k}V_{k,j}$) $$\forall i,j\ge1\quad (S^*A)_{i,j}=(AT^*)_{i,j}$$
boils down to:
$$\forall i,j\ge1\quad A_{i+1,1}=0\quad\text{and}\quad A_{i+1,j+1}=A_{i,j}$$
i.e. the (infinite) matrix $A$ is the transpose of Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: Ah, Ok, I think I understand. Because if you have $$S^* A = A T^*$$ then you can rewrite this as $$AT = SA$$ and if you write it out, you get for $AT$ and $SA$ each that $A_{i+1, 1} = 0$ and $A_{i+1, j+1} = A_{i,j}$

Comment: No, you cannot "rewrite this as $AT = SA$". You write out directly $(S^* A)_{i,j}=(A T^*)_{i,j}.$

Comment: So how do I write out directly $(S^* A)_{i,j}$ and $(AT^*)_{i,j}$? I mean, I don't even know how  $S^*$ and $T^*$ look like (in the form of a matrix), so how should I know how to write it out?

Comment: $(S^*)_{i,j}=(S_{j,i})^*.$ And $(S^*A)_{i,j}=\sum_k(S^*)_{i,k}A_{k,j}.$

Comment: Ok, I think I see it now. Thanks

Comment: Why exactly do we get $A_{i+1,1} = 0$ and $A_{i+1, j+1} = A_{i,j}$?

Comment: Simply develop both sides of $(S^*A)_{i,j}=(AT^*)_{i,j},$ using the definition of the product (recalled in my anser) and the description of $S^*$ and $T^*.$

Comment: I get $(A)_{i+1,j} = (A)_{i,j-1}$, so by that I get $(A)_{i+1,j+1} = (A)_{i,j}$, but why $(A)_{i+1,1} = (A)_{i,0} = 0$? Is this just some sort of "universal law" that $A_{i,j} = 0$ if $i$ or $j$ is equal to 0?

Comment: You get $A_{i+1,j} =A_{i,j-1}$ only when $j-1\ge1.$ When $j=1,$ what you get is $A_{i+1,j} =0.$

Comment: But why is it equal to zero?

Comment: $(AT^*)_{i,1}=\sum_kA_{i,k}(T^*)_{k,1}=\sum_kA_{i,k}0=0.$